# Polymer paper-input-decorator updateLabelVisibility() is not working

Tags: polymer

I don't know how I am supose to use the **updateLabelVisiblity()** function on a **paper-input-decorator** element. This should work but it doesn't!

In my plunker a normal **inputs value** is connected to a **paper-inputs value**. Whenever I type something in my normal input a function is called. That function calls **validate()** and **updateLabelVisiblity**.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WSQKbGmHTYiQlqM8C4Xz?p=preview) and here is my Polymer-element.

```
<polymer-element name='my-input'>
  <template>
    <h3>Paper input (linked)</h3>
    <paper-input-decorator id='myPaperInput' label='Field' error='error' floatingLabel autovalidate>
      <input is='core-input' pattern='^[0-9]*$' value='{{something}}'>
    </paper-input-decorator>
    <h3>Normal input (linked)</h3>
    <input value='{{something}}' on-keyup='{{mykeyup}}'>
    <p>
      Why doesn't the label show above the paper-input when i start typing in the <b>Normal Input</b>?
    </p>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      mykeyup: function(){
        this.$.myPaperInput.validate();
        this.$.myPaperInput.updateLabelVisibility();
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**Solved**

```
mykeyup: function(){
    var p = this.$.myPaperInput;
    p.validate();
    p._autoLabelVisible = p.querySelector('input').value !== '' ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: Hm.. It actually works for me. Whenever I type a non-numeric character the "error" label appears in your plunker.

Comment: Hi @Andy I can also see the **error** label. What I can't see is the **floating label**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what's happening. The updateLabelVisibility requires the value in order to show the floating label. However instead using updateLabelVisibility you can also do this hack:

```
this.$.myPaperInput._autoLabelVisible = false;
```

Which basically just hard sets the value that updateLabelVisibility is setting.

Here is your code, just updated:

http://plnkr.co/edit/l4xQBv7PKft2zqARnPu1?p=preview

Reference:
https://github.com/Polymer/paper-input/blob/master/paper-input-decorator.html#L474